# The labels for my Sankey diagram (R, Plotly) do not show properly on the online version of my Shiny dashboard, but behave correctly locally

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

So I'm working on a Shiny dashboard, which I deployed on an AWS EC2 instance. It behaves exactly the same both locally and online save for one detail: the labels on the right hand side do not behave properly!

Here is the online version of the Plotly Sankey diagram in question:

[image: Text]

Here is what I see locally when I run the app through RStudio.

[image: Text]

There's absolutely no difference among any files. I don't see why the rendering of the labels should differ on both versions, but anyway, here's the relevant part of the code inside server.R:

```
  # gender_sankey
  nodes <- c('Hombres', 'Mujeres', unique(gender_df$UltimoGradoEstudios))
  nodes <- nodes[c(1,2,4,3,5,7,12,10,8,6,11,9)]  
  gender_df$count <- 1
  hom_stud <- aggregate(count ~ UltimoGradoEstudios, FUN = sum, 
                        data = gender_df[gender_df$hom == 1,])
  muj_stud <- aggregate(count ~ UltimoGradoEstudios, FUN = sum, 
                        data = gender_df[gender_df$muj == 1,])

  # Setting the sources and targets
  hom_stud$src <- 0
  muj_stud$src <- 1
  hom_stud$tgt <- c(2,4,3,11,5,8,6,9,7)  
  muj_stud$tgt <- c(2,4,3,11,5,8,10,6,9,7)

  # Setting the positions for the nodes
  node_x <- c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
  node_y <- c(0,1,-10:-1)     # NOTE: Probably one of the fishy parts (2/2)
  colors <- c('#C7FFA9','#E4A9FF','#2424FF','#2477FF','#248EFF','#249FFF',
              '#24B3FF','#24C7FF','#24DEFF','#24F8FF','#24FFF8','#24FFEE')
  
  # NOTE: Probably one of the fishy parts (1/2)
  # Button to select/de-select all
  observe({
    if (input$selectall_sankey > 0) {
      if (input$selectall_sankey %% 2 == 0){
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, 
                                 inputId = "schoolSelect",
                                 choices = list("Doctorado" = 'Doctorado',
                                                "Maestría" = 'Maestría',
                                                "Licenciatura" = 'Licenciatura',
                                                "Pasante/Licenciatura trunca" = 'Pasante/Licenciatura trunca',
                                                "Profesor Normalista" = 'Profesor Normalista',
                                                "Técnico" = "Técnico",
                                                "Preparatoria" = "Preparatoria",
                                                "Secundaria" = 'Secundaria',
                                                "Primaria" = "Primaria",
                                                "No disponible" = 'No disponible'
                                                ),
                                 selected = c(choices = list("Doctorado" = 'Doctorado',
                                                             "Maestría" = 'Maestría',
                                                             "Licenciatura" = 'Licenciatura',
                                                             "Pasante/Licenciatura trunca" = 'Pasante/Licenciatura trunca',
                                                             "Profesor Normalista" = 'Profesor Normalista',
                                                             "Técnico" = "Técnico",
                                                             "Preparatoria" = "Preparatoria",
                                                             "Secundaria" = 'Secundaria',
                                                             "Primaria" = "Primaria",
                                                             "No disponible" = 'No disponible'
                                 ))
                                 )
        
      } else {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session = session, 
                                 inputId = "schoolSelect",
                                 choices = list("Doctorado" = 'Doctorado',
                                                "Maestría" = 'Maestría',
                                                "Licenciatura" = 'Licenciatura',
                                                "Pasante/Licenciatura trunca" = 'Pasante/Licenciatura trunca',
                                                "Profesor Normalista" = 'Profesor Normalista',
                                                "Técnico" = "Técnico",
                                                "Preparatoria" = "Preparatoria",
                                                "Secundaria" = 'Secundaria',
                                                "Primaria" = "Primaria",
                                                "No disponible" = 'No disponible'
                                 ),
                                 selected = c())
        
      }}
  })

  # Plot
  output$gender_sankey <- renderPlotly({
    hom_stud <- hom_stud[hom_stud$UltimoGradoEstudios %in% input$schoolSelect,]
    muj_stud <- muj_stud[muj_stud$UltimoGradoEstudios %in% input$schoolSelect,]
    node_x <- c(node_x[hom_stud$UltimoGradoEstudios %in% input$schoolSelect])
    node_y <- c(node_y[hom_stud$UltimoGradoEstudios %in% input$schoolSelect])
    colors <- c(colors[hom_stud$UltimoGradoEstudios %in% input$schoolSelect])
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      type = "sankey",
      orientation = "h",
      arrangement = 'snap',
      node = list(
        label = nodes,
        color = colors,
        x = node_x,
        y = node_y,
        pad = 15,
        thickness = 20,
        line = list(
          color = "black",
          width = 0.5
        )
      ),
      link = list(
        source = c(hom_stud$src, muj_stud$src),
        target = c(hom_stud$tgt, muj_stud$tgt),
        value = c(hom_stud$count, muj_stud$count)
      )
    )
    fig <- fig %>% layout(
      font = list(
        size = 10
      )
    ) %>% config(modeBarButtons = list(list('toImage'), list('resetScale2d')), displaylogo = F)
  })
```

**Packages used:** shiny, shinydashboard, shinythemes and plotly (same versions both locally and on server). dplyr, magrittr, and ggplot2 are on the same version as well.

**R version** in my computer is 4.0.2, R version in the server is 3.6.3

It's not the cleanest implementation, specially on the button part, but it works perfectly locally! Note that I marked the sketchy practices I used, and where the problem could lie. Basically the default node order wasn't cutting it because the position on the right hand side itself contains information (Doctorado > Maestría > Licenciatura> ...), so I kind of forced a different order for the nodes through `node_x` and `node_y`. The thing is, the implementation works locally! What could be the reason for it not to work online?

Comment: R version could be different on the Shiny server.  Then some of the packages you are using could behave differently based on their dependencies.

Comment: @YSB Any package/dependency comes to mind?

Comment: Please list the packages you are using in the question itself.  Also, version of R on Shiny server and your local laptop.

Comment: @YBS listed! Perhaps I should also update the R versions.. hope the server can handle it, as it only has 1GB RAM.

Comment: As you are using only 4 packages, and plotly depends on ggplot2 version >= 3.0.0, please ensure that ggplot2 is also installed on the Shiny server before installing plotly.  You may not be allowed to update R version on the server.  dplyr and magrittr are installed when you install plotly.

Comment: @YBS I just checked the version for every package used. They are exactly the same save for dplyr, which is 1.0.5 on server and 1.0.2 locally!  EDIT: Just updated dplyr locally, both on 1.0.5 now. Issue persists.

Comment: You will need a older version of `dplyr` or another package, as you have `R 3.6.3` on the server.  Try specifying the older version while installing as: `install.packages("latticeExtra", version="0.6-28")`